# Сэтить более одного типа параметров view

Tags: android, kotlin

Как для одной вьюшки сэтить два типа?

На данный момент у меня это происходит так

```
titleView.text = AppResource.getString(data.titleId)
```

Но так как у меня в конструкторе есть и строковые параметры, то как можно сэтить их данной вьюшке?

Для примера у меня есть класс где я передаю параметр LinkItem("some tet") - но естественно он его подчркивает, так как это String а не Int
Когда для LinkItem(R.string.sometext) всё ок.

Задача в том чтобы я мог и через id и просто строковые ресурсы закидывать в LinkItem

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Что значит сэтить два типа? И при чем тут конструктор?

Comment: @VladimirParfenov ну у меня иногда строки получаю формата R.string.sometext а иногда "sometext" и если для первого случая я сэчу текст AppResource.getString(data.titleId) то как мне поступить для "sometext"?

Comment: titleView.text = "sometext" , нет?  А выбор пути через if-else

Comment: @VladimirParfenov обновил вопрос, надеюсь сейчас чутка понятней задача..

Comment: Сделайте два конструктора, принимающие разные типы параметров

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fun getText(text:String):String{
    return text;
}

fun getText(id:Int):String{
    return AppResource.getString(id);
}
```

использование

```
titleView.text = getText("Some text");       // Через String
titleView.text = getText(R.string.sometext); // Через resourceId
```

Если нужно через конструктор

```
class LinkItem(val text:String) {
    constructor (id:Int): this(AppResource.getString(id))
}
```

Comment: Если возвращаете `String`, то и метод лучше назвать `getString()`, `getText()` обычно возвращает любую из имплементаций `CharSequence`.